# How to prevent child from affecting the parent

Tags: jquery, parent-child, jquery-events

How to prevent the CHILD element from affecting the PARENT element?

jQuery:

```
$("#parent").click(function() {
    alert('parent clicked');
});
$("#child").click(function() {
    alert('child clicked');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    click me - parent
    <div id="child">click me - child</div>
</div>
```

If you click the child, the parent is also activated and we have two alerts.

So how can I prevent the child from affecting the parent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("#child").click(function(event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    alert('child clicked');
});
```

Calling `event.stopPropagation()` will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

This is called `event bubbling` or `event propagation`. This can be prevented by adding `e.stopPropagation()` in your code. If you also want to stop the default behavior you can simply do: `return false;`.

`return false;` basically does both: [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). Which can be useful if you are using `<a>` tags for example and you want to prevent the page navigating away after a click.